# How can I correctly return a SpatialPolygonDataFrame from a user written function?

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to write a function that imports a shape file, prints the column names of `myshapefile@data` and then stores the shapefile as a named object. However, rather than returning a name object, `return()` prints the shapefile data in the console rather than saving it as an object in the environment.

This is the draft function, where `shp.path` is a string with the file path for shapefile:

```
get.map <- function(shp.path) {

  country.map <- rgdal::readOGR(shp.path)
  message("You will need to know which column has state names:")
  names(country.map@data)
  return(country.map)
}
```

It may be that a function is needed inside `return()` to define the object class, however adding `return(SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(country.map))` returns the error:

```
Error in nrow(data) : argument "data" is missing, with no default
```

Any advice on what to use instead? Leaving out `return()` altogether means the object is only defined locally, and can't be called upon in the next function.